# xamDataGrid - indenting nested levels

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a xamDataGrid with two levels of data. (see [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487544/infragistics-xamdatagrid-bound-to-hierarchical-data-how-to-notify-grid-of-chang) on SO).

There is very little visually that shows where one level of data starts and a seconds begins. Take a look at this snippet from the xamFeatureBrowser:

[image]

What I want, is to indent the second level a little. RecordPresenter has a [NestedContentMargin](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2010.3/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v10.3~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.RecordPresenter~NestedContentMargin.html) property, but it's read-only...

An alternative, would be to display some kind of thin footer for each second level grid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one turned out to be easier then expected. I'm sure I tried this before I asked the question, but for some reason, I failed. When I showed the problem to a colleague, he made it work just like that. :-/

So here is the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordPresenter}" x:Key="NestedRecordStyle">
  <Setter Property="Margin"  Value="20,0,0,0"/>
</Style>
```

and here's how I applied it to my nested fieldset:

```
<igDP:FieldLayout ParentFieldLayoutKey="MainLayout">
  <igDP:FieldLayout.Settings>
    <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings DataRecordPresenterStyle="{StaticResource NestedRecordStyle}"/>
  </igDP:FieldLayout.Settings>
  ...
</igDP:FieldLayout>
```

Just like that...

edit: Updated typo